# Running zookeeper from within application

Tags: distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper, configuration-management

I'd like to use zookeeper in one of my applications for distributed configuration management. The application is currently running in distributed environment and having to restart nodes for configuration files changes is a headache.

However, we want the zookeeper process to be started from within the application. The point is to reduced startup dependency and reduce operational cost. We've already have startup/shutdown scripts for the application and we need to reduce impact for operations team.

Has any one done something similar? Is this setup recommended or there are better solutions? Any tip or feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean in the same JVM or a separate JVM?

Comment: Preferably in the same JVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a [blog post](http://sourcedelica.com/blog/2013/02/adventures-in-clustering-part-2/) that describes how to embed Zookeeper in an application.  The Zookeeper developers don't recommend it, though, and I would tend to agree now, though I had the same rationale for embedding it that you do - to reduce the number of moving parts.

You want to keep your ZK cluster stable but you will need to restart your app to do code updates, etc, impacting the ZK cluster stability.

Ultimately you will end up using your ZK cluster for multiple apps and those extra moving parts will be amortized over a number of projects.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the informed response. I think I'll have to follow your advice and run zk as a separate process instead. It might be better for long term development.